# Htaccess - difference between: .* and .+

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can you tell me what is defference between .* and +* in htaccess? For example I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^profil/([0-9]+)/.*/(.*)$ index.php?url=profile/show/$1/$2 [L]
```

And if I have the same with .+ instead .+ it still works. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic regular expression stuff, and nothing specific to Apache configuration or mod_rewrite.

`*` means "Zero or more"

`+` means "One or more"

Answer (score 0):

The `.+` matches any char that occures 1 to n times

The `.*` matches any char that occures 0 to n times

This is not apache specific. You may want to look for regular expressions (regex) for further information:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Best regards